# Boost command line parser: how do I wrap add_options

Tags: c++, templates, boost, command-line, command

I would like to write a simple C++ wrapper for the Boost add_options function:

desc->add_options()
`(name, po::value<int>(), "");`

I'd like to call this with a wrapper function where I somehow pass the type in:

foo(char* name, ***) {

```
desc->add_options()
        (name, po::value<***>(), "");
```

Is there a relatively easy way to do this?

I am very unclear on how the Boost add_options function is declared and I am struggling with how to pass through the template value.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this was easier than I think. The member function in the wrapper class just has to be templatized. Then I can call the function from the main program with whatever type I have.

Sorry to waste this bandwidth... I was stuck on an incorrect tangent.